# Git +++ WARNING - You committed whitespace errors

Tags: git, warnings

I got the following errors while committing my stuff from windows pc to remote.

```
remote:  +++ WARNING - You committed whitespace errors
remote:  +++ WARNING - Please consider fixing them
remote:  +++ You can enable hook to prevent committing whitespace errors by renaming .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample to pre-commit
```

My git global config has the following **core.autocrlf** settings

```
$ git config --list | grep crl
core.autocrlf=input
core.autocrlf=true
```

Do I have change anything to get rid of this error?

Comment: You can configure the line ending handling per repository by adding a special .gitattributes file to the root folder of your Git repository. If this file is committed to the repository, it overrides the core.autocrlf setting of the individual developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `core.autocrlf`, since these are whitespace errors, not line ending errors.

The relevant config here is `core.whitespace`. Remove it if you don't want these errors (or, alternatively, fix them before comitting).